# Docker Build Fails on Cosign Verification: TLS Certificate Verification Error

Tags: docker, ssl, dockerfile, tls1.2, cosign-api

I'm encountering a TLS certificate verification issue during a Docker build process involving the verification of a container image using Cosign. Despite updating and installing CA certificates in the Dockerfile, the build process fails when running the `cosign verify` command. The error persists, indicating an issue with verifying the certificate from Sigstore's Transparency Log.

Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
# Build phase 1: Verification
FROM docker:stable-dind

# Update and install necessary packages
RUN apk update && apk add curl openssl ca-certificates && update-ca-certificates

# Install Cosign
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/sigstore/cosign/releases/latest/download/cosign-linux-amd64 -o /usr/local/bin/cosign && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/cosign

# Download Cosign public key
RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/main/cosign.pub -o /usr/local/cosign.pub

# Verify the image using cosign and your public key
RUN cosign verify --key /usr/local/cosign.pub gcr.io/distroless/java17-debian11 \
    || { echo "Cosign verification failed. Please check the image or public key."; exit 1; }
```

And the error message:

```
Error: getting Rekor public keys: updating local metadata and targets: error updating to TUF remote mirror: tuf: failed to download 8.root.json: Get "https://tuf-repo-cdn.sigstore.dev/8.root.json": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I'm wondering if:

- There are additional configurations needed for Cosign or Docker to recognize the CA certificates.
- The issue might be related to the network environment or specific to the Docker image I'm using (`docker:stable-dind`).

Any insights or suggestions to resolve this TLS certificate verification issue would be greatly appreciated!